# Using addClass() to target elements in a structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Context: I'm using jQuery and CSS to animate a shrinking sticky nav header in Wordpress. The jQuery code uses `addClass()` to append `.shrink` on a scroll trigger and then CSS can be used to target and manipulate it.

Please take a look at this simple code below.

```
jQuery(function(){
    var shrinkHeader = 250;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
            if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
                $('.site-header').addClass('shrink');
                $('.primary-navigation').addClass('shrink');
                $('.secondary-navigation').addClass('shrink');
                $('.menu-toggle').addClass('shrink');
            }
            else {
                $('.site-header').removeClass('shrink');
                $('.primary-navigation').removeClass('shrink');
                $('.secondary-navigation').removeClass('shrink');
                $('.menu-toggle').removeClass('shrink');
            }
        });

function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
});
```

I'm new to js and I'm aware it's not very pretty. I was hoping to append `.shrink` to all those elements in sequence but it seemingly only works for `.site-header`. I can't seem to target the other specified elements' `.shrink` (nothing happens when testing). Is it because `.site-header` sits on a higher level in the structure and the others are divs under it? Does one have to further specify to help `addClass()` find it?

The structure looks something like this

```
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="col-full">
        <nav class="secondary-navigation"></nav>
        <nav class="main-navigation">
            <button class="menu toggle"></button>
            <div class="primary-navigation"></div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

So what's going on here, why aren'r the other specified classes being appended with `.shrink` and what is the proper way to do so?

PS Is there any clever way to export the html div structure from a webpage using the browser devtools or something similar?

**---UPDATE 1---**

Trying some suggestions from the replies. The below CSS shows me the issue isn't with the CSS

```
/* Shows black bg, as it should */
.site-header {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
}

/* Shows blue bg on scroll, as it should */
.site-header.shrink {
    background: blue;
}


/* Now trying the same with .secondary-navigation */

/* Shows red bg, as it should */
.secondary-navigation {
    background: red;
}

/* Nothing happens here, bg still red */
.secondary-navigation.shrink {
    background: green !important;
}
```

So it only seems to work with `.site-header`.

- I tried changing the jQuery code into this
  `$('.site-header').find('.secondary-navigation').addClass('shrink');`
  but it didn't help.
- I can see `.site-header.shrink` exists when page is scrolled down,
  but there is no `.secondary-navigation.shrink`. It appears the class
  isn't added.
- I'm not sure what version of jQuery I'm using but it is the one
  bundled together with the latest version of Wordpress. But I doubt an
  outdated jQuery version is what's causing the issue here.
- I'm not 100% sure I'm showing you the correct div structure (I'm pretty new to web dev). I don't know of any way to export it so I just manually re-created it in my post from examining the page in the browser devtools. It should be fairly accurate though.

One idea that came to mind, could it perhaps be caused by the sequence Wordpress creates the div structure? Maybe `.site-header` is created early on page load before inserting the other elements later, and it somehow causes the jQuery code to not apply to them. But I'm not sure if the jQuery code would care about that and I don't even know how to check if it's the case, neither what could be done in that situation unless it can be solved by modifying the jQuery code somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same thing and the code works, in the Chrome-Console, where you can see elements of the page, the classes modifies every time the scroll down is >250. You can try by using the Chrome `F12` command to see the console and to check if the browser changes the classes. You can also try it in others browsers with the `F12` command on the keyboard. Check if the jQuery verison you are importing to your website is the last and updated one.
Check my CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/GabriSpree/pen/NVmNbE?editors=1010), then check the things I told above.
If any trouble continue showing, tell us.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work better for you:

```
  jQuery(function(){
      var shrinkHeader = 250;
          $(window).scroll(function() {
              var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
              if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
                  $('.site-header').addClass('shrink');
                  $(document).find('.primary-navigation').addClass('shrink');
                  $(document).find('.secondary-navigation').addClass('shrink');
                  $(document).find('.menu.toggle').addClass('shrink');
              }
              else {
                  $('.site-header').removeClass('shrink');
                  $(document).find('.primary-navigation').removeClass('shrink');
                  $(document).find('.secondary-navigation').removeClass('shrink');
                  $(document).find('.menu.toggle').removeClass('shrink');
              }
          });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
      return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      }
  });
```

Note that this code is tested and its only purpose is adding and removing the class `shrink` from specific elements on scroll, and it does that without an issue, if you're not seeing the result you want it might be because of your CSS.

Comment: I updated my post after trying your code, didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Are the other HTML elements loaded with the page or is it inserted with JS?

Comment: I'm not sure how Wordpress does it. I know that the menu system is somewhat modular and can be configured in .php files, that is why I think there may be a possibility that the <nav> elements get inserted at a later point during load and maybe that messes up jQuery targeting. I really have no idea though, I'm merely speculating here.

I also tried your new code but it still didn't work, and `.secondary-navigation.shrink` still can't be found in the webdev search. Does addClass() only work for certain HTML tags? Because `.site-header` is a <header> tag and the others are not